# How to scan a string for specific terms

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to scan user input text for specific words and then, when those words occur, print them to the console.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
char cArray[] = "example";
char cInput[] = "";
char cOutput[] = "";

printf("\nType your message:\n");
for (int y=0; y<1; y++){
    fgets(cInput, 120, stdin);
}
printf("\nInitialised character array:\n");
for (int x=0; x<1; x++){
    if(strncmp(&cInput[x], &cArray[x], 120) == 0){
        strncpy(cOutput, cArray, strnlen(cInput, +1));
        printf("%s\n", cOutput);
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Type your message:
example

Initialised character array:
Program ended with exit code: 120
```

Appreciate any feedback as I'm still learning :)

Thanks.

The edited code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 120

int main(){
char *cArray[MAX_STR_LEN] = {"example", "this"};
char cInput[MAX_STR_LEN] = "";
char cOutput[MAX_STR_LEN] = "";

printf("Type your message:\n");
for (int y=0; y<1; y++){
    fgets(cInput, MAX_STR_LEN, stdin);
    char * ptr = cInput;
    while((ptr=strstr(ptr, *cArray)) != NULL){
        strncpy(cOutput, ptr, strlen(*cArray));
        printf("Initialised string array:\n%s\n", cOutput);
        ptr++;
        }
    }
}
```

Works although I'm encountering a different problem now. The output only seems to register one word before it completes, thus only "example" is printed.

Output:

```
Type your message:
this is an example
Initialised string array:
example
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: Can you explain why you use `for (int y=0; y<1; y++)` loop, that execute `fgets` only once?

Comment: Really just so that it runs; at this point there isn't any need for it to run more than that. I plan to use it in an instant messaging context so unless there is an error, I'd assume each message only needs to be read once. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: O.k. - `for` is the remains of bigger program. In that case perhaps the `printf` and the second `for` loop should be inside the first `for`... otherwise reading data in the loop with `fgets` more than once will be "useless labor"

Comment: Can't get the formatting right for this comment but I've applied the code you provided earlier and nested the if statements within the first for. Works perfectly, thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need strstr function from string.h

```
const char * strstr ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

the following gives you an example of usage:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 120

int main(){
    char cArray[MAX_STR_LEN] = "example";  // string to be searched in the input string
    char cInput[MAX_STR_LEN] = ""; // input string
    char cOutput[MAX_STR_LEN] = ""; // buffer for found string

    printf("\nType your message:\n");
    for (int y=0; y<1; y++){     // this loop from original example looks strange, but it works
        fgets(cInput, MAX_STR_LEN, stdin);
    }
    // search in the input string
    char * ptr;
    if( ( ptr=strstr(cInput, cArray) ) != NULL)
    {
        //copy the string to cOutput
        strncpy(cOutput, ptr, strlen(cArray));
        // output the found string
        printf("String that was found: \n%s\n", cOutput);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("String was not found in the input!\n");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to all the strings, use the following loop instead of `if-else`:

```cpp
    // search in the input string
    char * ptr = cInput;
    while( ( ptr=strstr(ptr, cArray) ) != NULL)
    {
        //copy the string to cOutput
        strncpy(cOutput, ptr, strlen(cArray));
        // output the found string
        printf("String \"%s\" was found at position %d\n", cOutput, (int)(ptr - cInput + 1));
        // find next string
        ptr++;
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this point? I understand that str1 would be cInput and str2 would be cArray but I'm not sure where to place this statement in the code. Thank you.

Comment: Needs work - suggest `fgets(cInput, sizeof cinput, stdin);` and check its return value.  `strncpy(cOutput, ptr, strlen(cArray));` is troubling too. GTG

Comment: The last edit provides possibility to find more than one cArray in cInput. If you want to positions of appearances use expression `(ptr - cInput + 1)` as integer number.

Answer (score 2):

```
char cInput[] = "";
```

The sizeof this array is 1.

```
fgets(cInput, 120, stdin);
```

This is array out of bound write which will lead to undefined behavior.

Have

```
char cInput[120] = "";
```

You need to take care of

```
char cOutput[120] = "";
```

also. Since you are trying to write to this array after comparing.

Comment: This makes sense, I'll fix it. Thank you!

Comment: @masteryupa  please reflect changes to the posted code, so we can perform the evaluation so we can continue to help you.

Comment: @user3629249 I've added the changes I've made, hope it makes sense!